# Как свернуть форму при закрытии приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**FormClosed** - Возникает при каждом завершении работы с формой **после того**, как форма была закрыта, и определяет причины этого закрытия.

**FormClosing** - Возникает при каждом завершении работы с формой **до того**, как форма была закрыта, и определяет причины этого закрытия.

Как с помощью FormClosing свернуть приложение?

Есть примерный код, но не разберусь как его настроить (работает для кнопки "свернуть" FormMain_Resize, но не для кнопки "закрыть" FormMain_FormClosing):

```
    private void FormMain_Resize(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
        else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам надо сворачивать окно при нажатии кнопки "закрыть" - это делается вот так:

```
private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  }
}
```

Если вам надо при этом еще и убрать форму из панели задач - добавьте в метод `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`

Важно! Не отменяйте без веских причин закрытие формы при завершении приложения, закрытии из диспетчера задач или завершении работы компьютера - ни к чему хорошему кроме ругательств на зависшее приложение это не приведет.

*А что вы пытались сделать в своими условными операторами в вопросе - я не понял.*

Comment: Спасибо, помогли.